# SAPUI5: sap.m.TextArea cursor position

Tags: cursor, sapui5, textarea, tabcontainer

I'm using sap.m.TabContainer with items containing sap.m.TextArea's. If I switch between tabs,
the cursor position in the textarea's is reseted. I would like to keep the cursor position in the textarea's. Is there a possibility to store the current cursor position bevor leave and set the stored position on enter of the textarea?
Regards, Annie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sap.m.TextArea` inherits from the `sap.m.InputBase` which provides focus related APIs e.g. [`getFocusInfo`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.InputBase%23methods/getFocusInfo) and [`applyFocusInfo`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.InputBase%23methods/applyFocusInfo).

To get notified when the user enters or leaves the textarea you can add `onfocusin` and `onfocusout` as an [event delegate](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Element%23methods/addEventDelegate) and then store the focus info on focusout and apply the stored focus info on focusin. E.g.:

```js
var oFocusDelegate = {
  mFocusInfo: {},
  onfocusin: function(oEvent) {
    var oTextArea = oEvent.srcControl;
    var mFocusInfo = this.mFocusInfo[oTextArea];
    if (mFocusInfo) {
      oTextArea.applyFocusInfo(mFocusInfo);
    }
  },
  onfocusout: function(oEvent) {
    var oTextArea = oEvent.srcControl;
    this.mFocusInfo[oTextArea] = oTextArea.getFocusInfo();
  }
};
// add focus delegate to textareas
// TextArea required from "sap/m/TextArea"
new TextArea().addEventDelegate(oFocusDelegate);
```

Please see: https://jsbin.com/wusejifili/1/edit?html,output

Comment: +1. Great idea! Maybe we should also emphasize that `applyFocusInfo` and `getFocusInfo` are protected and that app developers should rather consider extending `sap.m.TextArea` instead.

Comment: Also not sure if `oEvent.srcControl` is part of public APIs

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great to track the changes of focus. But how to save and restore the cursor position in textarea? I've tried to use the DOM attributes scrollheight/scrolltop but without success.

Comment: @AnnieW. Could you elaborate more on "save and restore the cursor position in textarea"? Isn't that what the original question was?

Comment: it seems for me, that  getFocusInfo() and applyFocusInfo() don't get and set the current cursor position. If I add some lines to tab1, switch to tab2 and back to tab1 then the cursor is placed on line 1 and not at the saved last position

Comment: @AnnieW. get/applyFocusInfo are working find but I thought that this was only for keyboard handling (tab key). If you want to change the focus on the click event then you should add "onclick" to the event delegate object and run the same onfocusin code e.g. onclick: function(oEvent) { this.onfocusin(oEvent); }; However I would not suggest that, re-positioning the cursor might disturb the user.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the helpfull hints. I got something which works as needed replacing the handle onfocusin with onclick, finding the textarea element and calling elem.blur() and elem.focus()
Here you can find my coding: https://jsbin.com/sireweyeto/1/edit?html,output
Fell free to comment it and help me to code it better.
My primary goal was to give the user the possibility to return to the last editing position after switchng to other tab/textarea